# Get pylint-score for each file in project

Tags: python, pylint

I have a large project and would like to create an overview of the current linting status.

I thought about using the .json.output of pylint and writing a small script that creates a nice, colored overview in a .html file, so that I see the current score of the whole project, each directory and all modules.

However, if I run pylint over all files, I only get a general score. Is there a possibility to get the score for each file seperately?

My last solution would be to execute pylint seperately for each file, store the scores in an array and then create a html file directly.

Do you guys know something better?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for whole Project, but there is option for running for whole .py files inside a folder[Project folder]

```
pylint Your\folder\path
```

Give your path instead of filename.

Comment: Yes, but then I only get the score for the whole project and not for each individual file